# how do I specify a render cache context as universal?

Tags: caching

I want to a render array in my page to be cached, and I know that it's the same for every user in every circumstance.

How do I specify that its cache context is universal, rather than anything else?

Comment: The is no *universal* cache context. This is the default if you don't specify any cache context.

Comment: Cache contexts are used to vary the content - if there's no variance, there's no context to apply

Comment: I'm within a render context that's per-user, so presumably I need to specify a cache context to make the change of context?

Comment: Also, I thought the default for render arrays was user role?

Answer (score 3):

There is no *universal* cache context. This is the default for a render array if you don't specify any cache context.

Render contexts are merged upstream. Additionally you can configure required cache contexts which are added to all render arrays before they are rendered.

Out of the box Drupal requires these three contexts:

*core.services.yml*

```
parameters:
  renderer.config:
    required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
```

You can override the parameter in */sites/default/services.yml* (use *default.services.yml* as template).

Comment: If I don't specify contexts, then in `cache_render`, the key has `[languages:language_interface]=en:[theme]=bartik:[user.permissions]=e26039e109d3f06cf28210caa84de1e43c3b0150b9feea8398758e278b3d7e7e` so clearly it's varying by language, theme, and user permissions. That's not universal!

Comment: For a minimal install you could remove all of the three required contexts and decide for each render array your own set of cache contexts. This is not recommended for normal use cases, though, this might have security implications.